# ckeditor5 custom upload adapter

Tags: custom-adapter, image-upload, ckeditor5

When I try to select an image from the tool 'Insert image' the value of the loader is undefined and the image don't upload.
I've reading the documentation buy I can't find why my images don't move to my local folder 'uploads'. 
Here is the code, it's mostly copied from the documentation, but the image don't move.
If I write http://localhost/uploads in the browser, the path is correct.

```js
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/16.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>    

class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor( loader ) {
        // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    // Starts the upload process.
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                this._sendRequest( file );
            } ) );
    }

    // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
        if ( this.xhr ) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }
    // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://localhost/uploads', true );
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }
    // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;
        xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
            const response = xhr.response;
            if ( !response || response.error ) {
                return reject( response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText );
            }
            resolve( {
                default: response.url
            } );
        } );
        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            } );
        }
    }
    _sendRequest( file ) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append( 'upload', file );
        this.xhr.send( data );
    }
}

function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin( editor ) {
    editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
        // Configure the URL to the upload script in your back-end here!
        return new MyUploadAdapter( loader );
    };
}

ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    extraPlugins: [ MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ]
} );            

</script>
```